# Why am I getting negative one bytes for my output?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, output, metadata

I tried to develop a simple metadata visualizer tool using C for visualizer engine for "png" file but I'm getting -1 for my output and I don't know why. Can someone show me where is the error?

#include <stdio.h>

```
int main ()
{
    FILE *file_input;
    unsigned char c; //unsigned
    long int counter=0L;
    long int saizFail, curPos=0L, current=0L;
    
    if ((file_input = fopen("C:\\Users\\User\\Pictures\\timetable.png", "rb"))=NULL)
         printf("File cannot be opened");
                 
    fseek(file_input, 0L, SEEK_END); //
    saizFail=ftell(file_input);
    rewind(file_input);
    
    printf("File size = %ld bytes\n\n", saizFail);
    
    while (counter<100)
    {
        c=fgetc(file_input);
        printf("counter %ld >> %X\n", counter, c);
        counter++;
        
    }
    
    printf(">>File size = %ld bytes\n\n", saizFail);
    
    fclose(file_input);
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: `fgetc` returns `int`, not `unsigned char`, and you should check that the return value doesn't equal `EOF` before using it as a character.  In fact `fgetc` failed, for the reason that selbie explained, so `fgetc` returned `EOF` to indicate the failure, but your code wasn't paying attention and output it as `unsigned char` anyway, which explains the `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

You meant to use `==`, but used `=` instead.

This line:

```
if ((file_input = fopen("C:\\Users\\User\\Pictures\\timetable.png", "rb"))=NULL)
```

Should be:

```
if ((file_input = fopen("C:\\Users\\User\\Pictures\\timetable.png", "rb"))==NULL)
```